# Add button on Sliding Tab Layout fragment android xamarin

Tags: xamarin.android

I want to add a RecyclerView and button inside FragmentLayout1 in slide tab bag.
I made the following attempt, but the RecyclerView and button appeared with all tabs and not a specific tab. In addition to stopping the application when adding a pressure event to the button.

```
FragmentLayout1.axml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

  <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="341.0dp" />
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/buttonPanel"
    android:layout_width="162.5dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_gravity="top|end"
    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="0dp">
    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:id="@+id/button1" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: `RecyclerView ` is an Android widget that displays a collection of items in a list or a grid, enabling the user to scroll through the collection. It shows all the items. I am confused about what you want. Could you provide more details like screenshot, more code about Mainactivity?